# Excel Data Validation List as Formula in "Source" Field?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007.

Is it possible to enter a short list of allowed values directly into the "Source" field in the Data Validation -->Settings Tab?

If I want to allow a cell to have one of two values `NW` and `NE`, I know I can put those two values in to cells next to each other (e.g. `g1` & `g2`) and refer to them in the Source field: `=g1:g2`.

What I would like to be able to do is have the source field contain the two values directly.  None of these work:

```
={"NW","NE"}
=["NW","NE"]
=("NW","NE")
```

And this one:
`={"nww";"nws"}`  not only doesn't work but results in a dialog reading *You may not use unions, intersections, or array constants for Data Validation Criteria*.

Maybe that is my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. It happens to be so simple it gets overlooked. All you have to do is enter the values separated with a coma. There is no special code required.

> NW, NE

[image]